# React - async API call on form submit + local state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, formik

```
  submitForm = (data: Object) => {
    this.setState({
      isShowMessage: true,
    });

    if (this.props.isAdd) this.props.addRestaurant(removeEmptyValues(data));
    else
      this.props.updateRestaurant(
        { data, selectedId: this.state.selectedId },
        this.state.selectedId,
      );
  };
```

The code snippet above would return a memory-leak error on my console whenever i click the submit button on the form twice. How to prevent this error?

[image]

Comment: Does the component actually unmount from the page?

Comment: No, the component will not do unmounting when the user submits to the form.

Comment: Is the whole code too big to post? This error usually occurs when handling an event associated with an unmounted component, but as you say it does not unmount it's kind of confusing...

Comment: basically when the user submits the form. it will show a message(toast) component base on the local state isShowMessage

                      {this.state.isShowMessage &&
                        this.props.status === 200 &&
                        !this.props.loading && (
                          <Message
                            severity="info"
                            message="Info"
                            detail="Data hase been successfully saved."
                            timeout={3000}
                          />
                        )}

Answer (score 0):

You should use async await for async calls and also disable the submit to prevent multiple calls.

Comment: how to convert this code into async await? eventually the button is disabled when it gets submitted.